# Batch gradient descent with scikit learn (sklearn)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm playing with a one-vs-all Logistic Regression classifier using Scikit-Learn (sklearn).  I have a large dataset that is too slow to run all at one go; also I would like to study the learning curve as the training proceeds.

I would like to use batch gradient descent to train my classifier in batches of, say, 500 samples.  Is there some way of using sklearn to do this, or should I abandon sklearn and "roll my own"?

This is what I have so far:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

# xs are subsets of my training data, ys are ground truth for same; I have more 
# data available for further training and cross-validation:
xs.shape, ys.shape
# => ((500, 784), (500))
lr = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression())
lr.fit(xs, ys)
lr.predict(xs[0,:])
# => [ 1.]
ys[0]
# => 1.0
```

I.e. it correctly identifies a training sample (yes, I realize it would be better to evaluate it with new data -- this is just a quick smoke-test).

R.e. batch gradient descent: I haven't gotten as far as creating learning curves, but can one simply run `fit` repeatedly on subsequent subsets of the training data?  Or is there some other function to train in batches?  The documentation and Google are fairly silent on the matter.  Thanks!

Comment: Your best bet maybe to look into the source code of this library.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you want is not batch gradient descent, but stochastic gradient descent; batch learning means learning on the entire training set in one go, while what you describe is properly called minibatch learning. That's implemented in `sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier`, which fits a logistic regression model if you give it the option `loss="log"`.

With `SGDClassifier`, like with `LogisticRegression`, there's no need to wrap the estimator in a `OneVsRestClassifier` -- both do one-vs-all training out of the box.

```
# you'll have to set a few other options to get good estimates,
# in particular n_iterations, but this should get you going
lr = SGDClassifier(loss="log")
```

Then, to train on minibatches, use the `partial_fit` method instead of `fit`. The first time around, you have to feed it a list of classes because not all classes may be present in each minibatch:

```
import numpy as np
classes = np.unique(["ham", "spam", "eggs"])

for xs, ys in minibatches:
    lr.partial_fit(xs, ys, classes=classes)
```

(Here, I'm passing `classes` for each minibatch, which isn't necessary but doesn't hurt either and makes the code shorter.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, which I will try ASAP.  Regarding definitions, I was following the terminology from Andrew Ng's Coursera class; in his nomenclature, stochastic gradient descent involved changing the gradient with every training sample, and what you call minibatch he called batch gradient descent.  But naming notwithstanding, I can see that this is what I was asking for -- thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnJ: actually SGD can be used in batch, minibatch or online (one sample at a time) mode. The terminology I used here is that of prof. Hinton's Coursera NN/ML class, which I've found so far to be consistent with most of the literature.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. Your answer worked well for me so far as well. Do you recommend that class?  Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnJ: yes, it's quite good. It continues where Ng left off and if you like dry wit, you're in for a treat.

Comment: @larsmans, is there any way to pass, variable features to partial_fit function?

Comment: @FredFoo do you have any resources that confirm `SGDClassifier` supports multi-label classification? The docs and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335853/scikit-multilabel-classification-valueerror-bad-input-shape say that it's the opposite

Comment: does SGDClassifier's fit method do batch gradient descent or online (one sample at a time) gradient descent?

Comment: @Nagabhusha Baddi according to my knowledge fit method uses one sample at a time for training while partial_fit method uses batch gd for training. Crt me if im wrong.