# scikit multilabel classification: ValueError: bad input shape

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, stochastic-process

I beieve `SGDClassifier()` with `loss='log'` supports Multilabel classification and I do not have to use OneVsRestClassifier. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036630/batch-gradient-descent-with-scikit-learn-sklearn)

Now, my dataset is quite big and I am using `HashingVectorizer` and passing result as input to `SGDClassifier`. My target has 42048 features.

When I run this, as follows:

```
clf.partial_fit(X_train_batch, y)
```

I get: `ValueError: bad input shape (300000, 42048)`.

I have also used classes as the parameter as follows, but still same problem.

```
clf.partial_fit(X_train_batch, y, classes=np.arange(42048))
```

In the documentation of SGDClassifier, it says `y : numpy array of shape [n_samples]`

Comment: What are the shapes of `X_train_batch` and `y`?

Comment: (300000, 1048576) and (300000, 42048) respectively, both are scipy sparse matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `SGDClassifier` does *not* do multilabel classification -- it does *multiclass* classification, which is a different problem, although both are solved using a one-vs-all problem reduction.

Then, neither SGD nor [`OneVsRestClassifier.fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.fit) will accept a sparse matrix for `y`. The former wants an array of labels, as you've already found out. The latter wants, for multilabel purposes, a list of lists of labels, e.g.

```
y = [[1], [2, 3], [1, 3]]
```

to denote that `X[0]` has label 1, `X[1]` has labels `{2,3}` and `X[2]` has labels `{1,3}`.

Comment: Thanks Larsmans. I further worked on it and got all my answers clarified. But I am worried now as there are about 42000+ labels, I might have to come up with 42K estimators for each of the labels separately and I do not think I can do all these in a single machine. Thinking of using ipython parallel and starcluster.

Comment: ValueError: You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a binary array or sparse matrix instead - the MultiLabelBinarizer transformer can convert to this format.