# Sklearn Implementation for batch gradient descend

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, gradient-descent

What is the way of implementing Batch gradient descent using sklearn for classification?
We have ***SGDClassifier*** for Stochastic GD which will take single instance at a time and ***Linear/Logistic Regression*** which uses normal equation.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036630/batch-gradient-descent-with-scikit-learn-sklearn (although perhaps not exactly what you are asking)

Comment: A negative answer (i.e. showing that you can actually *not* do something), as the one below, is a valid answer indeed. I kindly suggest you accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The possible answer to the question as pointed out in the [other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036630/batch-gradient-descent-with-scikit-learn-sklearn) as well from sklearn [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.partial_fit):

> SGD allows minibatch (online/out-of-core) learning, see the
> partial_fit method.

**But is `partial_fit` really a batch gradient decent?**

SGD: The gradient of the cost function is calculated and the weights are updated using the gradient decent step ***for each sample***.

Batch/Mini Batch GD: The gradient of the cost function is calculated and the weights are updated using the gradient decent step ***once per batch***.

So Batch GD with batch size of 1 == SGD.

Now that we are clear about definitions lets investigate the code of sklearn `SGDClassifier`.

The docstring of `partial_fit` says

> Perform one epoch of stochastic gradient descent on given samples.

But this is not a batch GD but it looks more like a helper function to run `fit` method with `max_iter=1` (infact commented as same in docstrings).

`partial_fit` calls `_partial_fit` with `max_iter==1`. [Reference link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py#L1193)

`fit` method calls `_fit` which calls `_partial_fit` with `max_iter` set to the assigned\default maximum iterations. [Reference link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py#L595)

### conclusion:

`partial_fit` does **not** really do batch GD, i.e it is not calculating the gradients and updating the weight per batch but rather doing so for each sample.

There seems to be no mechanism in sklearn to do batch gradient descend.

Comment: That was my conclusion, too - hence my comment along with the linked question; +1 for summing it up...