# How to do minibatch gradient descent in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, mini-batch

Is it possible to perform minibatch gradient descent in sklearn for logistic regression? I know there is `LogisticRegression` model and `SGDClassifier` (which can use `log` loss function). However, `LogisticRegression` is fitted on whole dataset and `SGDClassifier` is fitted sample-by-sample (feel free to correct that statement, but this is how I understand stochastic gradient descent).

There is also `partial_fit` method, but that is available only for SGD. I believe that if I use `partial_fit` for SGD it will update weights each time it goes over next dataset sample (just like normal `fit` method). So if I provide chunk of 10 samples to `partial_fit` it does 10 updates - but that is not what I want.

What I need to get, is to update weights after each nth sample, just like in minibatch gradient descent. From what I read about `LogisticRegression` it can use something called `warm_start` which means, that weights from previous `fit` method are set as initial for current `fit`.

If this theory about `warm_start` is true, could I just use `fit` method multiple times, each time only on one minibatch? Or is there any other way to do minibatch gradient descent in sklearn?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552139/sklearn-implementation-for-batch-gradient-descend) which is very similar, except it does not discuss the `warm_start` idea, so that is why I asked again.

Comment: The clear (and AFAIK correct) conclusion of the linked thread is "*There seems to be no mechanism in sklearn to do [mini] batch gradient descend*", and `warm_start` actually does not alter that fact (again, the fitting will be per sample); I'm closing this as a duplicate.

Comment: @desertnaut thats not correct I believe if you use `warm_start` with `LogisticRegression` (not with SGD!) I thought that if you do fit for each batch of data separatedly, then you get minibatch gradient descent, but I am not sure. However, you closed my question, so I will probably at this solution to questions you linked here as duplicates

Comment: `warm_start` in LR does not even use GD; you may use it to simulate a "batch-like" learning with the solvers used in LR (except for `liblinear`), but this will no longer be GD, which is what your question is about. If this is not exactly what you meant to ask, you are always welcome to open a new question (you are not anyhow "penalized" for questions closed as duplicates).